# str_replace not working with txt file PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

str_replace doesn't seem to be working as we expect it to.

We have a text file and we're trying to remove part of the file.

```
while(!feof($bodyfile)) {

    $content = @fgets($bodyfile);

    $content = str_replace("MARGIN","",$content);
```

(Obviously fopen is used to open the file as 'r')
Strangely enough, finding and replacing M works? but not margin..

Comment: What does `$content` look like ??

Comment: `str_replace` is case-sensitive!`str_ireplace` is not!

Comment: yes we are trying to find the uppercase MARGIN and replace it with nothing...

Comment: $content is a text file that can be handled line by line. why has someone voted this question down?

Comment: can you add .. the content to pastebin .. i would like to test myself

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE:

[`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) function reads only 1 line at the time, and by putting that line in your `$content` variable, you're overwriting the replacement for previous line, and doing it over and over again.

Try with this:

```
$content = "";
while(!feof($bodyfile)) {

    $line = @fgets($bodyfile);

    $content .= str_replace("MARGIN","",$line);
```

So, what this code does is reading the line and assigning it to the `$line` variable, and then adding the replaced string to your `$content` variable.

---

By adding `@` sign in front of your functions, you're [suppressing errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) which that function gives.
Try to remove `@` from your `@fgets` and see if there's any error.

Try `var_dump($content)` or `echo $content` to see if file is loaded correctly.

Remember that [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) is case sensitive.

Comment: var_dump shows the whole thing is a bunch of strings. which is what we want.
removing the @ didn't do anything as there were no errors to suppress. the file looks to be loading fine. 
the file is basically a line by line text document of data that has html in. 
May I point out that also, we can str_replace ONE character but when choosing multiple is doesnt work... I thought this was because the file was being read character by character but i dont think that is the case after some investigation with line breaks

Comment: @Nikola K. reading one line is valid and they can be so many text in a line .... it is `fgetc` that many not be valid in this case ...

Comment: Sorry - that one just loops forever :(.

could this be a character encoding issue?

Comment: @30secondstosam that is why i asked you to add the content to pastbin .. understand what we are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
$str=implode("",file('somefile.txt'));
$fp=fopen('somefile.txt','w');
$str=str_replace('MARGIN','',$str);
//OR
//$str=str_ireplace('MARGIN','',$str); for case insensitivity
fwrite($fp,$str,strlen($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the file is a UTF-16 character encoding rather than UTF-8 for some obscure reason. Converted, now my method originally works!

Thanks to all for suggestions